Understanding usage of std::for_each with structs
I am trying to understand how below code works, from cpp reference website:
std::vector<int> v{3, -4, 2, -8, 15, 267};

struct Sum
{
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }
    int sum {0};
};

// invoke Sum::operator() for each element
Sum s = std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), Sum());    
std::cout << "sum:\t" << s.sum << '\n';

I don't quite understand what is happening here.

What is s before going through for_each
What happens to s in every iteration
If we wanted to just assign one element to s, how would we do it (Sum s = ??)


What is s before going through for_each  What do you mean by that? The passed in Sum() gets returned from for_each. What happens to s in every iteration Nothing, s exists after the function returns. If we wanted to just assign one element to s, how would we do it (Sum s = ??) s is an object of Sum. If you want to assign a single element to s.sum, just do it.

You are using s.sum in the output. You can also do s.sum = 12; to change its value.

Ignore Sum s =  for a second and assume the statement is just std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), Sum()); instead. Which part of the statement do you have a question about or is that part clear to you? If you are only confused by Sum s =, then see on the cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) that for_each simply returns (a copy of) the third argument at the end.

And anyway, this is not a very good example as I would use std::accumulate to sum up the values (without a struct).

@BoP: I'd go a step further: this is a terrible example that makes something similar into a nearly unrecognizable mess.

std::for_each is a bit outdated (if you're not using the parallelized version).  Just use range based for loops or indeed use std::accumulate

What are C++ functors and their uses? and Using STL algorithms, is it better to pass a function pointer or a functor?

Although the criticisms of the code are valid, there's still a real technique in there that is confusing you.
Sum is a functor or function object.



What is s before going through for_each

s doesn't exist until after the for_each finishes, so that doesn't make sense. Ignoring that, s is initialized with the result of std::for_each. As you can see from the documentation, it's just returning a copy (well, move) of whatever you passed as the third argument, which was Sum().
That is, you pass for_each a default-constructed Sum which has the member sum initialized to zero. It gives you that back at the end, and you initialize s from it.



What happens to s in every iteration

Still doesn't exist yet. But the Sum you passed in gets its operator() method called exactly as the documentation says.



If we wanted to just assign one element to s, how would we do it (Sum s = ??)

There's no point writing a functor like sum if you don't want it to add things for you!
If there's only one element in the container (or in the iterator range you pass), then operator() will only be called once, and the resulting sum will have the value of 0 +  that single element.


